# SVG Image disappears for half of sping cycle (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css, svg

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta  name ="viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> Loading Fenster Spinner </title>
    </head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0; 
        }
        .container {
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%; 
            position: absolute;
            transform: translate(-50%,-50%); 
        }
        @keyframes spin {
            0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
            100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
        }
        #fenster-logo-3_1 {
            animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <svg width="110" height="101" viewBox="0 0 110 101" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                <rect id="fenster-logo-3_1" width="110" height="101" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
                <defs>
                <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
                <use xlink:href="#image0_1_27" transform="matrix(0.00149925 0 0 0.00163285 0 -0.0274096)"/>
                </pattern>
                <image id="image0_1_27" data-name="fenster-logo-3.png" width="667" height="646" xlink:href=<(huge link that is way too many characters to put here)>
              </defs>
              </svg>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to spin a svg logo just in a circle for a loading screen, however, whenever I try to do it. The thing disappears for half of the spin. Does anyone know why that is happening. I am very new to CSS and HTML so any help will be very appreciated.

If anyone knows a simple way to take a png and spin it in the middle of a screen using CSS/html that will also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you perform a `transform: rotate` on an element, it depends on the [`transform-origin` CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) that you have specified, which is the top-left corner by default when used inside a SVG. (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform-origin)

For your particular case, you need to add the following to your `#fenster-logo-3_1` CSS style: `transform-origin: center;`.

However, I would recommend transforming the outer wrapper element (`.container` or your `svg`) instead as transform within a SVG can have different behaviours depending on the browser.

The easiest solution with minimal changes to your code to move the logic to the parent container is the following:

```css
.container {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform-origin: center;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about transforming the outer wrapper element. As your solution did work for the most part, but it still gets cut off at the edges a little bit when spinning. I really appreciate your help. 

EDIT: Nevermind! I figured it out, thank you so much

Comment: @JamesLoVerde Added a code snippet for your case to move to outer wrapper element. You can remove the style definitions for `#fenster-logo-3_1`